# Let $\lambda \notin [0, 1]$ and $x \neq y$ such that $x,y\in \partial C$. Then $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \notin \overline C$

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space, $C$ a convex subset of $X$, and $x,y\in \partial C$. Suppose $\lambda \notin [0, 1]$ and $x \neq y$. I would like to ask if $z:= \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \notin \overline C$. This is intuitively true when $C$ is a line segment or a circle in $\mathbb R^2$. However, I do not have a proof.

Could you elaborate on this conjecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the conjecture is not correct. A counter example is a square in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: accept your own answer and move on? Clean up the queue...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I would like to accept it immediately, but the site requires me to wait for $2$ days before doing so. Please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uXgF.png).

Comment: Aha, weird. Maybe it's to avoid abuse (pimping your rep?)..